# using ng-repeat with the bootstrap navbar element

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a nav bar using bootstrap.Following is the code.

```
<div>
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use the ng-repeat for the options. I tried the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" ng-repeat="option in navBarOptions">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#">{{ option.optionText }} </a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the JS part.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('MainController',['$scope', function($cope) {
$cope.navBarOptions = [
   {
      optionText: 'Home',
   },
   {
      optionText: 'Option 1',
   },
   {
      optionText: 'Option 2',
   },
];
}]);
```

Thanks. I am fairly new to this domain.Let me know if i missed something very trivial.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Nitek Hey Nitek, the code did not create the nav Bar. I was hoping someone could probably troubleshoot that for me..!! Thanks for the response..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat **the `li` elements**, not the `div` where the `ng-controller` resides:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="option in navBarOptions">
            <a href="#">{{option.optionText}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

NB: Looking at the generated DOM would have gave you a clue about what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Michael, i did use this code, but the nav bar was still not created.!!

Comment: Any error in the console? Did you add `ng-app="myApp"` ?